# Xcode and Swift Localization - Recover base language

Tags: swift, xcode, localization

I am learning iOS development (with swift). In this case, I was trying to do `localization` for an example project and I decided to delete the `base language` (Development language) in order to configure it again. I got surprised when I could not add any language. I mean, i click the add button for languages and select the language, but, In the next window (Choose files and reference languages to create XXXX localization) the list is empty.

Every tutorial I have found adds language using the development language (base) as the begining, but cannot find how to implement first.

Could you help me implementing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the `iOS project` with `IntellijIDEA` IDE ypu could right click on the project `rootfolder` or the `project.pbxproj` file and check the `history` and revert back to the historical state that you wish.

In case you had it under `git`, its even better as you can be sure that you are avle to revert it by comparing it with a branch that has the right state.